# How to create a thin arrow using background/linear-gradient combo?

Tags: html, css

I want to use the background-image prop instead of doing a pseudo element like :after/:before unless that is the preferred way. This is what I have so far:

```
 .container select {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 50%, transparent 0),
      linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 50%, transparent 0),
      linear-gradient(45deg, #444 53%, transparent 0),
      linear-gradient(-45deg, #444 53%, transparent 0);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

It is an arrow, but it isnt positioned correctly at all and I can't seem to get it to move really at all with `background-position`. Another thing is there a way to size this?

Something else I noticed is that the arrow has some not smooth edges. It looks like it was written with a marker and on the edges it didn't "write".

[image]

```css
.selectContainer {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #f8f8f8 50%, transparent 0),
      linear-gradient(-45deg, #f8f8f8 50%, transparent 0),
      linear-gradient(45deg, #444 53%, transparent 0),
      linear-gradient(-45deg, #444 53%, transparent 0);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<select type="text" class="selectContainer">
  <option value="">state</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, could you include your HTML and make a snippet? Thanks

Comment: @sol Done! Hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using `%` as the unit in your `linear-gradient` is causing pixel rounding, and making the arrow edges look rough.

Instead, you can use `px`. You can adjust the size of the arrow by playing around with the values.

To reposition, use the `background-position` property.

```css
.selectContainer {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #f8f8f8 46px, transparent 0),
      linear-gradient(-45deg, #f8f8f8 46px, transparent 0),
      linear-gradient(45deg, #444 50px, transparent 0),
      linear-gradient(-45deg, #444 50px, transparent 0);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  background-position: -25px -5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<select type="text" class="selectContainer">
  <option value="">state</option>
</select>
```